# Why does this regex, using "not" & a backref, require a lazy match?

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

When using the not `^` operator in combination with a back reference, why do I need to use a lazy match? It seems like the `not` should break the match.

For example:

```
<?php
preg_match('/(t)[^\1]*\1/', 'is this test ok', $matches);
echo $matches[0];
?>
```

[**Will output `this test`**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/BPDeLx), instead of `this t`, in spite of the fact that the middle `t` does not match `[^\1]`. I need to use [**`/(t)[^\1]*?\1/` to match `this t`**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WWlTQW).

Furthermore

```
preg_match('/t[^t]*t/', 'is this test ok', $matches);
```

[**does match only `this t`**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AE8YhY).

What is going on, and what am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because the `\1` here is not a backreference inside a character class. The `\1` is interpreted as the character with ASCII value 1.

You could use a negative lookaround instead to get the effect you want:

```
'/(t)(?:(?!\1).)*\1/'
```

Comment: I had just added that exact example to my own answer.  I guess great minds think alike.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks, regexes get me every time!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use backreferences inside character classes.  `[^\1]` means "any character other than `1`".

Instead, use `/(t)(?:(?!\1).)*\1/`.

`(?:...)` is a non-capturing group

`(?!...)` is a "negative look-ahead", asserting that the subexpression doesn't match

`(?!\1).`, when `\1` is a single character, means "any character that does not match `\1`